# SetSplitCharacters adding spaces on URL

Tags: itext7

I am using ITextSharp 7 for pdf rendering.
I have a url -

*https://vvvvvvveeeeeeeerrrrrryyyyyyylllllloooooonnnnggggguuuurrrrllllll.com*

I am using

```
SetSplitCharacters(a,e,i,o,u)
```

so that it can break the long text
The resultant causes space '_' to appear in the middle of the url causing the entire url to be broken url giving page not found.

Is there a solution for this -  I cannot add

```
SetSplitCharacters(,'/\)
```

as I have other text on the page that is been rendered - that has to be broken at a,e,i,o,u.

Any suggestions/workaround?
I am using C# code with The ItextHtml plugin.

Comment: On which element do you set split characters? Do you have a long paragraph with a lot of text and an url inside it?

Comment: It's a url and text labels both

Comment: Could you add your code? It's still not clear what's going on and what's your problem.